# What happens if a sorcerer can't ever cast wish again?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, wish

A level 17 Sorcerer casts the *Wish* spell for an effect that would trigger the repercussions, rolls the d100, and finds they are never able to cast it again:

> Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you suffer this stress.

Does that mean there is a spell sitting in their 9th level spell slot that they can't ever use or get rid of? Or would the sorcerer be able to swap that spell out for another 9th level?

I am not interested in the homebrew rulings, and a RAW answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Yeah, you would end up with a spell you can't cast. Fortunately, at level 17, you are not stuck with it forever, because:

> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the sorcerer spells you know and replace it with another spell from the sorcerer spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

So at level-up, you could drop Wish and replace it with something else. Once you hit 20th level though, if you still have it, you're pretty much stuck with it.

You could at that point ask your DM whether you could replace it as a down-time activity, though. It's not in the books but it seems reasonable that you don't get stuck with it for all eternity when a lesser Sorcerer would have a way to get rid of it...

Answer (score 17):

### What happens? You can never cast wish again.

Yes, the sorcerer still knows Wish and that 'spell known' slot is unavailable. Until they reach 18th level when any sane sorcerer would swap it out as per the rules. However, if it happens when you are 20th level, you're stuck with it.