# Are there any ways to regain the ability to cast Wish after suffering the 33% chance to never be able to cast it again?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

Are there any ways to restore your ability to cast [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) after suffering from the stress described in the final paragraph and losing your ability to cast it?

From the description:

> The stress of casting this spell to produce any effect other than duplicating another spell weakens you. After enduring that stress, each time you cast a spell until you finish a long rest, you take 1d10 necrotic damage per level of that spell. This damage can't be reduced or prevented in any way. In addition, your Strength drops to 3, if it isn't 3 or lower already, for 2d4 days. For each of those days that you spend resting and doing nothing more than light activity, your remaining recovery time decreases by 2 days. Finally, there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever again if you suffer this stress.

Comment: Very related again on [Can I use Divine Intervention or Wish to regain Wish?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/101962)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No.

The rules do not describe any way to restore your ability to cast Wish after suffering from the stress described in the final paragraph and losing your ability to cast it.  You quoted it yourself:

> there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast wish ever
>   again if you suffer this stress.

That "ever again" seems pretty definitive.

So, I think you have to say, per the rules, no, nope, nada, not happening.  It says "ever again" and that's that.

### But . . . .

I personally don't like that.  It sort of reads like after suffering the stress the DM says, "okay, Wally, roll a 6-sider: 1 or 2, no more wish for you.  Ever again. Ever. Again."

What fun is that?  It just sits there like a dead fish.  And that doesn't feel very D&D-like to me.  And in D&D everything is up to the DM.  So ask your DM.

Personally, I prefer it like this:

DM: After such a mighty casting, you're weak as a kitten, etc., etc.
Wally: But can I cast wish again?
DM: I don't know, can you?
Wally: But . . .
DM: Guess you'll have to try.
Wally: Okay, after I recover, I cast wish, etc.
DM: Roll a 6-sider: 1 or 2, nothing happens.
Wally: 1!  That's it?  Is there any way I could restore my ability?
DM: Roll an arcana check.
Wally: 17.
DM: You always heard no, but there was a rumor that the library at Faraway-and-Hard-to-Get-to contained a tome that suggested a way.
Wally: Off we go!
::adventures ensue::
Librarian: Ah, yes, perhaps the Scroll of Suzy the Inscrutable.  I can neither confirm nor deny that that volume contains the information that you seek, but bring me the still-beating heart of a sphinx and you can have a look.
::adventures ensue::
Librarian: Mmm, delicious!  I love fresh Sphinx heart!
DM: The scroll suggests the Donboddame in her cave in the Mountains of Doom may know of a way.
Wally: @#%@
::adventures ensue::
Donboddame: Did you bring cookies?  I like the ones with truffles from the Endless Forest.  Very hard to find they are.
Wally: @^%$@
::adventures ensue::
Donboddame: Mmm, mrph, good cookie!  I once heard that if you bathe in the blood of a freshly killed ancient red dragon and then drink a potion made from the tears of a unicorn then there's a chance.
Wally: I wish you'd drop dead!
Donboddame: Lucky for me . . . .

So check with your DM.